# PhpStorm, remove annoying notice when you are editing an html

Tags: phpstorm

Does anybody know how to remove those annoying notice when you are editing html with PhpStorm. It just make me crazy. Please look at screenshot....
[image]

Comment: I see such notice for a first time. Could you please provide an example of such file that has this behaviour? Or maybe even some simple project (in case it depends on some other settings/files) -- not necessarily working.

Comment: It happens when you are working with html markup inside of .php or .html file.
Every time you change cursor position it's become shown.

Comment: It's just dawned on me that the problem is in this construction 
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="header_top_a" style="none" />
PhpStorm doesn't know what it is. But it's still irritate me...

Comment: My only suggestion ATM is to add `jdoc` namespace definition (or whatever the proper name is) so that it's known to PhpStorm so that it will not treat `jsdoc:include` as invalid. Ask on Joomla forums maybe? As for actual hint ... not sure. There is one option in 132.xxx branch (disable light bulb icon, that *may help*, unsure) .. but PhpStorm is currently on 131.xxx one.If you wish -- try IntelliJ IDEA v13 (it's in EAP stage, no separate license required) -- see if it will do any better there with that option disabled.

Answer (score 7):

A little bit more attention has resolved my question)
[image]